# Как сделать так, чтобы программа выводила числа по-типу "032"?

Tags: c++

Пишу код, на задачу. 
Вот условие: Натуральное число n дано, нужно увеличить на 1 все его четные цифры и уменьшить на 1 все его нечетные цифры. 
А если, например, есть число `123`, то программа должна отобразить цифру `032` 
Но в этом случае программа не отображает число `032`, а число `32`, то есть `0` в начале, оно не засчитывается. Нам нужно как-то это изменить. 
Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int number, temp, result, result2, temp2;
    number = 0;
    temp = 0;
    result = 0;
    result2 = 0;
    temp2 = 0;
    std::cin >> number;
    while(number != 0) {
        temp = number % 10;
        if(temp % 2 == 0) {
            temp++;
            result = (result * 10) + temp;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        else if(temp % 2 != 0) {
            temp--;
            result = (result * 10) + temp;
            number = number / 10;
        }
    }
    while(result != 0) {
        temp2 = result % 10;
        result2 = (result2 * 10) + temp2;
        result = result / 10;
    }
    std::cout << result2 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужен ноль в начале, то это уже не число. Так что делаем из числа строку, для каждого символа строки проделываем необходимые манипуляции. Выводим получившуюся строку.

Comment: sprintf("%03d", result2) вместо std::cout?

Comment: Используйте для вывода [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) с модифицируемым форматом. Что-то в духе `char fmt[] = "%0xd"; ... printf(fmt, result);`. Перед вызовом printf заменяете в fmt `x` на нужную цифру (подсчитав в ходе своих вычислений, сколько изначально было цифр в числе)

Comment: @Denys в [стандартной библиотеке C](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf)

Comment: @avp А как именно заменить в fmt `x` на нужную цифру?

Comment: `fmt[2] = digit;`

Comment: @avp Вот код:
`
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char fmt[] = "%0xd";
    int number = 0, digit = 0;
    cin >> number;
    while(number != 0) {
        number /= 10;
        digit++;
    }
    fmt[2] = digit;
    cout << fmt[2] << "\n";
}
`
И когда я запускаю программу, отображается следующее:
[Фото что происходит с кодом](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1blcgz6sC96jDuJsmurjbzuxya6E-1PWm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Denys, это `fmt[]` для `printf()`, а не cout (printf в С++ тоже работает, изучите и пользуйтесь)

Comment: @avp Зделал через printf() - такая же ситуация.

Comment: Где-то ошиблись. Замените `std::cout << result2 << "\n";` в конце своего кода на  `char fmt[] = "%0xd\n";     fmt[2] = digits + '0';     printf(fmt, result2);` Это точно работает (по крайней мере в linux g++) (естественно, добавьте `digits++;` внутрь какого-либо цикла)

Comment: Я сделал это, спасибо. Только вы изначально написали по-другому, вы написали, что мне нужно сделать так `fmt[2] = digit;`, а теперь написали `fmt[2] = digit + '0'` именно из-за этого действия `+ '0'` все изменилось к лучшему и программа сработала, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в данном случае проще будет обрабатывать ввод посимвольно, и преобразовывать необходимым образом каждый символ.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin; using std::cout;

int main()
{
    char digit = 0;

    cin >> std::ws;
    while (cin.get(digit) && digit >= '0' && digit <= '9')
        cout << char( 1 - (digit - '0') % 2 * 2 + digit );
}
```

Либо воспользоваться функциями [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) и [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) из заголовочного файла `<iomanip>` для форматирования вывода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cin; using std::cout;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long num = 0, res = 0, pow = 1;
    int width = 0;

    cin >> num;
    do {
        res += (1 - num % 2 * 2 + num % 10) * pow;
        num /= 10;
        pow *= 10;
        ++width;
    } while (num > 0);

    cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(width);
    cout << res;
}
```

Comment: Честно говоря, мне трудно понять эти строки.

Comment: Какие конкретно? Что-то ведь понятно?